# Query column and get a list of all values that are not there

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm looking to do a query against a table that has sample data like:

```
1000
2000
3000
4000
5000
```

The column is called `sampleData` and query it and get a list of all that are not there.

Example: `where sampledata not in (1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000)`
should respond with `6000,7000` or similar to that.

Is that possible?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and **your** attempt.

Comment: Sql Server 2008 has reached its formal end of life. That means it no longer gets any updates -- not even critical security patches! -- and hasn't for several years now. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

Yes

```
with valuestocheck(val) as (
   SELECT * FROM ( VALUES (1000),(2000),(3000),(4000),(5000),(6000),(7000)) t(val)
)
SELECT * 
FROM yourtableyoudidnotname x
LEFT JOIN valuestocheck on x.sampleData = valuestocheck.val
WHERE valuestocheck.val is null
```

You are left joining to the table with all the items you want -- this means that if an item is not in the table the left join will be null. Your filter on this case in the where clause to get the items you need.

Comment: thanks. I tried this and im getting an error. this is what i did.
with valuestocheck(val) as (
        VALUES ('1000','2000','3000','4000','5000','6000','7000','38035987','38037416')
)
SELECT * 
FROM Buying_Request x
LEFT JOIN valuestocheck on x.sampleData = valuestocheck.val
WHERE valuestocheck.val is null





Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'VALUES'.

Comment: ok i got it to run now with the updated code you provided but its giving me a response of all the data in the table. in my example it should only give me 1000 2000 3000 4000 5000 6000 7000 . the only real values in this table are 38035987 and 38037416.

with valuestocheck(val) as (
        select * from ( VALUES('1000'),('2000'),('3000'),('4000'),('5000'),('6000'),('7000'),('38035987'),('38037416')) t(val)
)
SELECT * 
FROM Buying_Request x
LEFT JOIN valuestocheck on x.orderid = valuestocheck.val
WHERE valuestocheck.val is null

Comment: whats interesting is if i say is not null it gives me 38035987 and 38037416 which are correctly in that database and in the sample data....but if i say is null it just gives me my entire database when its supposed to give me just the ones from my sample data that are not in it.

Comment: @kivi12k -- I think I don't understand your use case -- you want the ones that are not in the list you gave?  this you should use valuestocheck is null

Comment: @joelcoehoorn -- I guess SQL Server does not use the standard syntax for VALUES?

Comment: @Hogan Not in 2008.

Comment: @kivi12k -- is it possible the data in the table is a different type?  We used integers here -- maybe your table has floats or string for the sampledata column -- can you check the type of that column?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @T table(testval int)
INSERT INTO @T(testval)
    SELECT 1000 union
    SELECT 2000 union
    SELECT 3000 union
    SELECT 4000 union
    SELECT 5000 

DECLARE @AllValues TABLE (val int)
INSERT INTO @AllValues(val)
    SELECT 1000 union
    SELECT 2000 union
    SELECT 3000 union
    SELECT 4000 union
    SELECT 5000 union
    SELECT 6000 union
    SELECT 7000 union
    SELECT 8000 union
    SELECT 9000

SELECT Val 
FROM @AllValues A LEFT JOIN @T T on T.testVal = A.val
WHERE T.testVal is null
```